# Nodejs invalid regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I run the following command:

```
node_modules/.bin/jsdoc -r --destination /home/user/public_html/jsdoc-meta/ node_modules/jsdoc/
```

and this is what I get. I don't find the error in the regular expression:

```
/home/user/node_modules/jsdoc/lib/jsdoc/name.js:77
    var regexp = new RegExp('^' + memberof.toString() + REGEXP_SCOPE_PUNC);
                 ^
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^harmonyTestFixture.ES6 Template Strings.`\u{000042}\u0042\x42\u0\102\A`[~,#,.]/: Unterminated character class
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at nameIsLongname (/home/user/node_modules/jsdoc/lib/jsdoc/name.js:77:18)
    at Object.exports.resolve (/home/user/node_modules/jsdoc/lib/jsdoc/name.js:114:21)
    at Doclet.postProcess (/home/user/node_modules/jsdoc/lib/jsdoc/doclet.js:171:20)
    at newSymbolDoclet (/home/user/node_modules/jsdoc/lib/jsdoc/src/handlers.js:190:23)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/user/node_modules/jsdoc/lib/jsdoc/src/handlers.js:226:29)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Visitor.visitNode (/home/user/node_modules/jsdoc/lib/jsdoc/src/visitor.js:283:16)
    at Visitor.visit (/home/user/node_modules/jsdoc/lib/jsdoc/src/visitor.js:177:27)
    at Walker.recurse (/home/user/node_modules/jsdoc/lib/jsdoc/src/walker.js:533:27)
```

Comment: IT should be `^harmonyTestFixture.ES6 Template Strings.\\u{000042}\u0042\x42\\u0\102\A[~,#,.]`

Comment: escape `\u` chracter. what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node (or V8 much rather) tries to parse this as a UTF8 escape sequence:

```
/^harmonyTestFixture.ES6 Template Strings.`\u{000042}\u0042\x42\u0\102\A`[~,#,.]/
                                                                ^^^^^^
```

However, due to the backslash between the `\u0` and the `102` there's missing characters, thus the error message (`Unterminated character class`). Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you could either remove that backslash:

```
/^harmonyTestFixture.ES6 Template Strings.`\u{000042}\u0042\x42\u0102\A`[~,#,.]/
                                                                  ^
```

or escape the backslash:

```
/^harmonyTestFixture.ES6 Template Strings.`\u\{000042\}\u0042\x42\u0\\102\A`[~,#,.]/
                                                                    ^^
```

Comment: I grepped the source and found ```'`\\u{000042}\\u0042\\x42\\u0\\102\\A`'``` which makes a lot of sense. Maybe it's then an error and all of the backslashes need to be double escaped?

Comment: I don't know why these where in Jsdoc, but i finally commented out tests and this passed through.

Comment: Glad you could fix it.